# TicTacToe minimax function returns moves in order of the board

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I simply followed the structure of basic Minimax functions with:

```
def player(board):
if Terminal(board) != False:
    return None
else:
    if turn(board) == "X":
        value,move = max_value(board)
        return move + 1
    else:
        value,move = min_value(board)
        return move + 1
    

def max_value(board):
    global arg
    if Terminal(board) != False:
        ut = Utility(board)
        return ut,None
    else:
        v = -1000
        move = None

        for action in Actions(board):
            aux,act = min_value(Result(board,action))
            if aux > v:
                v = aux
                move = action
                if v == 1:
                    return v,move
        return v,move

def min_value(board):
    if Terminal(board) != False:
        ut = Utility(board)
        return ut,None
    else:
        v = 1000
        move = None
        print(Actions(board))
        for action in Actions(board):
            aux,act = max_value(Result(board,action))
            if aux < v:
                v = aux
                move = action
                if v == -1:
                    return v,move
        return v,move
```

player is called initially and returns the best possible move. The other functions are:

```
def Actions(board = list):
    possible_moves = []
    n = -1
    for move in board:
        n += 1
        if move == None: 
            possible_moves.append(n)
    return possible_moves

def Result(board,action):
    dc_board = board.copy()
    dc_board[action] = turn(board)
    return dc_board

def Terminal(board):

    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] and board[0] != None:
        return board[0]
    elif board[3] == board[4] == board[5] and board[3] != None:
        return board[3]
    elif board[6] == board[7] == board[8] and board[6]!= None:
        return board[6]
    elif board[0] == board[3] == board[6] and board[0] != None:
        return board[0]
    elif board[1] == board[4] == board[7] and board[1] != None:
        return board[1]
    elif board[2] == board[5] == board[8] and board[2] != None:
        return board[2]
    elif board[0] == board[5] ==board[8]  and board[0]!= None:
        return board[0]
    elif board[2] == board[4] == board[6] and board[2] != None:
        return board[2]
    else:
        return False
def Utility(board):
    result = Terminal(board)
    if result == False:
        return 0 
    elif result == "X":
        return 1
    elif result == "O":
        return -1
    else:
        print("Result:")
        print(result)
        print("Board:")
        print(board)
        raise "Utility conditions were not met."
```

I checked the output of all of them independently yet they all seem to be logical. The player function simply returns moves in the order of the TicTacToe board, if a coordinate is full, it skips it, eg: ' if board[move] != None: board[move + 1] = "O" '

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see this a lot, the problem is in your Utility function. Your return value needs to be dependent on player turn. Right now you are returning 1 if 'X' wins, even if it is 'O' turn.

Also I think you need to return higher values to be able to later include depth in the score (to always find the shortest path to victory). Therefore change 1 and -1 to 10 and -10.

Pseudo code:

```
elif (result == "X" and turn == "X") or (result == "O" and turn == "O"):
    return 10
elif (result == "X" and turn == "O") or (result == "O" and turn == "X"):
    return -10
```